# CasperJS: How to click a link in a frame that closes the page, without error

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a form I'm filling and one of the fields requires picking an object from a list in a popup window. The list is inside an iframe on the popup page, and clicking the link in the list closes the popup and places the value in the form on the original page.

My problem is with my setup I'm clicking the link within the iframe kills the popup, and then on exiting the `this.withFrame()` function I get the error

`Error: cannot access member 'switchToParentFrame' of deleted QObject`

Here's roughly what my code looks like.

```
this.withPopup(/popup/, function() {
    this.withFrame('listFrame', function() {
        // do stuff to get the right link selector
        this.click(link);
    });
});
```

If there's a way to click the link from outside the `withFrame()` function?

Comment: That's a good question. I wonder why you were downvoted. This looks like a bug. You might want to [create a new issue on github](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues). If you do, add a complete script with a proper page to reproduce the problem, so that it will be fixed.

Comment: damn, thats not the answer I want :P. Will do in the morning, because if it is a bug I give up for tonight

Comment: Any success with my workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Popups are generally pretty screwed atm. Heres a link to the issue on github. https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/1174#issuecomment-77136687

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use the PhantomJS functions [`page.switchToFrame()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/switch-to-frame.html) and `page.switchToParentFrame()` and explicitly check if the `page` is still valid. Maybe a check is not even necessary, because the `page` instance is already destroyed.

```
this.withPopup(/popup/, function() {
    this.page.switchToFrame('listFrame');
    this.click(link);
});
```